# How to programmatically control the iOS strong password suggestions for a React Native secureTextEntry enabling/disabling them based on value?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a single password field, and I want to enable/disable the iOS password suggestion-based input for it.
The different scenarios are as follows:

1. When the password input is empty, it can accept a strong password suggestion from iOS.
2. If an iOS-strong password suggestion was applied to the text input, the values in the input should remain editable, and no more password suggestions from iOS should be accepted.

However, the issue is that once passwords are suggested, the yellow UI of the iOS password suggestion did not go away.

Facing the same issue and its open state.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21911

I have attempted to resolve the problem by trying different approaches

1. Programmatically changing the textContentType property

`textContentType={values?.password ? 'oneTimeCode': 'newPassword'}`

2. By rendering two input fields - one with the newPassword textContentType prop and another with the oneTimeCode prop.

Any solution to this problem?Thanks looking forward.